# SQL Populate table with random data from a selected list of records

Tags: python, sql

Is there a SQL code that could populate my table in the following matter every 3seconds?
I currently am struck for quite some time. Any kind souls?

I wish to populate the id in increasing manner, position from values 1-3, 
the action from the list of the given list (weightlifting,shoutout,dumbbells,facewipe,tornado, muscle)
and the sync from values 0-3.

[image]

Comment: What is your database ? Show us the data example with what you start with...

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find your database's RANDOM function. For sql-server:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (position, action, sync)
SELECT
   CAST(RAND() * 3 AS INT) + 1, 
   CASE CAST(RAND() * 8 AS INT) 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Weighlifting'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Shoutout'
        WHEN ...
   END,
   CAST(RAND() * 4 AS INT)
```

I'm assuming the id column is set to auto-increment and will take care of itself.

The RAND function, as most random number generator functions, will return a number in [0, 1). Multiply, add and floor the result accordingly, to get an integer in the desired range.

I suggest you consider creating a table with the possible values for the "action" column and replacing the column with a FK to that table. It will make it simpler both to populate and maintain this table.

Comment: yes, it is working now, thank you so much. however, under the actions column, it is producing null values. any idea why?

Comment: @uiu808 I must have miscounted the possible text values. On the line where you produce a random number for this column: `CASE CAST(RAND() * 9 AS INT)`, you need to multiply by the number of different values you want to get. I counted 9 strings, so I wrote this line to produce 9 different integers (0-8). It seems the values are actually 8 (0-7). So `CASE CAST(RAND() * 9 AS INT)` can sometimes produce 8 as a result, but the case statement apparently doesn't map 8 to a string, so it returns null. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @uiu808 Actually, you have a different numbers of strings in your description than you have in the header of the column in your picture. If you have even fewer strings, you should adjust accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the update! what about the id? how do i get the id to increase per row as the code runs?

Comment: @uiu808 It's safer to let your database manage that automatically. Look up how you can create an auto-increment field in your particular DBMS. For example, in SQL Server you can set the IDENTITY property of the column.